# Is web analytics similar to data science?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, career, market-basket-analysis, consumerweb

I just finished PhD and initially wished to work on data science and deep learning. However, after some rounds of interviews, I have been offered a job of web analytics and business intelligence at a medium size company. Is there any similarity with data science, and is there a future in it?

Because of some precarious situation, I have to accept this job, but should I keep looking for another job meanwhile, or will the experience be helpful to rise up the ladder or join a big brand?

Comment: Business intelligence is a good entry into data science, and experience counts. If you want, negotiate to have a Data Scientist title.

Comment: @Emre So the titles are interchangeable, whatever the work?

Comment: No, they are not.

Answer (score 1):

We can see Web Analytics like an application of Data Science concepts. Almost a field of it. Usually it's very close to Business Intelligence for marketing aims and the main goal is to analyse users information.
So it's about marketing.